# Print only not null values

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I am trying to print only not null values but I am not sure why even the null values are coming up in the output:

Input:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import linecache

i=1
read_url = linecache.getline('stocks_url',1)
while read_url != '':
        page = requests.get(read_url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        percentage = tree.xpath('//span[@class="grnb_20"]/text()')
        if percentage != None:
                print percentage
        i = i + 1
        read_url = linecache.getline('stocks_url',i)
```

Output:

```
$ python test_null.py 
['76%']
['76%']
['80%']
['92%']
['77%']
['71%']
[]
['50%']
[]
['100%']
['67%']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting empty lists, not `None` objects. You are testing for the wrong thing here; you see `[]`, while if a Python null was being returned you'd see `None` instead. The `Element.xpath()` method will *always* return a list object, and it can be empty.

Use a boolean test:

```
percentage = tree.xpath('//span[@class="grnb_20"]/text()')
if percentage:
    print percentage[0]
```

Empty lists (and `None`) test as false in a boolean context. I opted to print out the first element from the XPath result, you appear to only ever have one.

Note that `linecache` is primarily aimed at caching Python source files; it is used to present tracebacks when an error occurs, and when you use `inspect.getsource()`. It isn't really meant to be used to read a file. You can just use `open()` and loop over the file without ever having to keep incrementing a counter:

```
with open('stocks_url') as urlfile:
    for url in urlfile:
        page = requests.get(read_url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        percentage = tree.xpath('//span[@class="grnb_20"]/text()')
        if percentage:
            print percentage[0]
```

Comment: After using percentage[0], here is what I get:

$ python test_null.py 
76%
81%
92%
77%
71%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_null.py", line 12, in <module>
    print percentage[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: if percentage:   ...is quite different from...   if percentage != None:

Comment: @user3198755: then you are not using `if percentage:`, because that'd only be true if there was at least 1 element to index.

Comment: @NickFellingham: right, it wasn't immediately clear whom you were addressing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your code and it should work:

```py
if percentage != []:
```